# Non-existing graphic file only produces warning. Why?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, xetex, luatex

The following LaTeX code only throws warnings when compiling with pdfLaTeX or luaLaTeX. In contrast, compiling with XeLaTeX leads to an abort, as I actually expect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Bla bla

\includegraphics{fooBarBaz.jpg}

Bla bla

\end{document}
```

I find the behavior strange.

Comment: You got a warning, but you didn't notice it. BTW, warning doesn't stop of compilations.

Comment: it is a bit inconsistent, probably xetex should issue a warning in draft mode too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, my second sentence in my comment should be: *BTW, warning with exception when is used `xelatex` engine, doesn't stop of compilations  of documents.*

Comment: @Zarko it errors and stops the compilation for me with xelatex.

Comment: Missing images should no produce an error and stop compilation in `draft` mode.  It is really  `xelatex` who does not work as expected.